# Grails: Cannot parse json with error No signature of method: static grails.converters.JSON.parse()

Tags: json, grails

I have a android program which will send a json data to server side with Grails.
When the server side received the request, it should parse the json data.

However Grails always show error as below:

> No signature of method: static grails.converters.JSON.parse() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray) values: [[[password:123, roleId:1, userName:abcde, userId:abc, email:c@a.com]]]

Here is the code of Grails side:

Domain class:

```
class User {

    String userId
    String userName
    String password
    String email
    int roleId

    static constraints = {
        userId size: 1..20, blank: false, nullable: false, unique: true
        userName size: 1..50, blank: false, nullable: false
        password size: 1..20, blank: false, nullable: false
        email size: 1..100, blank: true, nullable: true
        roleId blank: false, nullable: false
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
import grails.converters.JSON 
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject    

class userController {
        def index() {
            def requestJson = request.JSON
            def user = new User(JSON.parse(requestJson))

            //Save
            if (!user.save(failOnError: true)) {
                user.errors.each {
                println it
            }
        }
}
```

And I was wonderring is it correct of the receved JSON format since it was showing three [[[ and ]]] in the error log. But at the android side, the generated Json should as below:

```
[{"email":"c@a.com","password":"123","userName":"abcde","userId":"abc","roleId":1}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client is sending a JSON array.

```
[{"email":"c@a.com","password":"123","userName":"abcde","userId":"abc","roleId":1}]
```

which is parsed to a list of map(s) when you access the payload from the `request`. So `request.JSON` in this case would be:

```
[
    [ 
      "email":"c@a.com",
      "password":"123",
      "userName":"abcde",
      "userId":"abc",
      "roleId":1
    ]
]
```

You have to have the below logic in controller to get a list of `User`s:

```
def index() {
    def users = request.JSON.collect { new User( it ) }

    //Save
    if (!user*.save(failOnError: true)) {
        user*.errors.each {
            println it
        }
    }
}
```

It depends on how you want to save, I wanted to indicate that you have to deal with a list of users instead of one user from the payload.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, its working! 
But I am not really understand what do you mean of "have to deal with a list of users instead of one user from the payload.". Could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: The way you were creating `User`, you were expecting there will be one user in the payload, but in real you receive an array of users as the payload (in this case there was only one user in the list). So you have to handle a list of users in the payload.